# How to open browser and set html data to it by intent, Android

Tags: android, html, web

I want open the android browser, and set the html data on it. I do not want to use webview control. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to android, but to generic morden browsers:

You can make entire document into a long string of URI, and then locate that to show the original document. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme.

Someone provides a handy web-based tool to convert any document into Data URI string:
http://www.dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/

The size limit varies among the specific web browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
String URL= [url];
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can save the html file locally on the SD and give the url to it.

Good Luck

Comment: Yeah, just understood that I didn't answer correctly, see the update.